# does dispatch_async copy internal blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, reference-counting

Given the following (manual reference counting):

```
void (^block)(void) = ^ {
    NSLog(@"wuttup");
}

void (^async_block)(void) = ^ {
    block();
}

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), async_block);
```

Will "block" be copied rather than thrown off the stack and destroyed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe, the answer is Yes.

The outer block will be asynchronously dispatched which causes the runtime to make a copy on the heap for this block. And as shown below, and described in the [Block Implementation Specification - Clang 3.4 Documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Block-ABI-Apple.html), the inner block's imported variables are also copied to the heap.

In the OP's example we have a "imported const copy of a Block reference".

I'm using the example in the Specification:

```
void (^existingBlock)(void) = ...;
void (^vv)(void) = ^{ existingBlock(); }
vv();
```

The Specification states that the `copy_helper` and `dispose_helper` functions are needed:

> The copy_helper function is passed both the existing stack based pointer and the pointer to the new heap version and should call back into the runtime to actually do the copy operation on the imported fields within the Block.

The following example code in the Specification is difficult to decipher (and actually lacks the description what happens when the outer block is copied to the heap). Anyway, it appears the specification tries to show that imported variables of inner blocks will be (recursively) copied into the raw storage area of the outer block.

When the outer block will be copied on the heap, it seems imported variables of inner blocks will eventually live on the heap as well.

Well, intuitively, this all makes sense.

I made a small test program which will demonstrate this:
(you have to debug and examine the disassembly in order to figure out whats going on under the surface).

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


void foo(int param)
{
    int x0 = param;
    int x1 = param + 1;
    void (^existingBlock)(void) = ^{
        int y0 = x0;
        int y1 = x1;
        printf("&y0: %p\n", &y0);
        printf("&y1: %p\n", &y1);
        printf("&x0: %p\n", &x0);
        printf("&x1: %p\n", &x1);
    };

    void (^vv)(void) = ^{
        int y2 = x0;
        int y3 = x1;
        existingBlock();
        printf("&y2: %p\n", &y2);
        printf("&y3: %p\n", &y3);
        printf("&x0: %p\n", &x0);
        printf("&x1: %p\n", &x1);
    };

    printf("Stack: &x: %p\n", &x0);
    printf("Stack: &x: %p\n", &x1);

    printf("------- on main thread -------\n");
    vv();

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
        printf("------- on thread 2 -------\n");
        assert(vv);
        sleep(1);
        int y4 = x0;
        int y5 = x1;
        vv();
        printf("&y4: %p\n", &y4);
        printf("&y5: %p\n", &y5);
        printf("&x0: %p\n", &x0);
        printf("&x1: %p\n", &x1);
    });
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        foo(1);
        sleep(2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Stack: &x: 0x7fff5fbff868
Stack: &x: 0x7fff5fbff864
------- on main thread -------
&y0: 0x7fff5fbff70c
&y1: 0x7fff5fbff708
&x0: 0x1001081e0
&x1: 0x1001081e4
&y2: 0x7fff5fbff76c
&y3: 0x7fff5fbff768
&x0: 0x10010a588
&x1: 0x10010a58c
------- on thread 2 -------
&y0: 0x1000e5d9c
&y1: 0x1000e5d98
&x0: 0x1001081e0
&x1: 0x1001081e4
&y2: 0x1000e5dfc
&y3: 0x1000e5df8
&x0: 0x10010a588
&x1: 0x10010a58c
&y4: 0x1000e5e6c
&y5: 0x1000e5e68
&x0: 0x10010a5e8
&x1: 0x10010a5ec
```

When the block is executed on the main thread, it lives on the stack (as shown by the addresses of the local and imported variables). When executed via `dispatch_async` the runtime has copied the block - including the inner blocks, as can be seen by the addresses of the local and imported variables of the blocks.

We can set a breakpoint at the `copy_helper_block` function, and in fact, the program stops there once, in order to copy the block `vv` to the heap.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

From the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_async) on `dispatch_async` :

**block**

`The block to submit to the target dispatch queue. This function performs Block_copy and Block_release on behalf of callers. This parameter cannot be NULL.`

So, `async_block` is copied.

Per [this discussion](http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/9/15/ios4-blocks-2) , `block` (inside of `async_block` in your example), will be a `readonly copy` within `async_block`

Answer (score 0):

`block` is `retain`ed (not copied per sé) for being caught in another block `async_block` just like ordinary objects. Copying of the block is the result of the block object being sent a `[block retain]` message which called an overridden `retain` method that copied the block.

Comment: where did you get this information from? And what would retaining a block do?

Comment: Blocks inherits from `NSObject` (both Apple `_NSBlock` and GNUstep `GSBlock` classes respectively, both are private however, only exception: LLVM's implementation in compiler-rt used a C-based approach that is strikingly similar to CoreFoundation) so they got `objc_retain()`'ed when caught in another block just like your `NSArray`s and `NSString`s

Comment: @Gabriele Petronella Since iOS 6.0 and Mac OS X 10.8, Maxthon is correct when saying that blocks are "Objects". ARC will manage them as retainable object pointers. That DOES NOT mean, however that blocks are automatically copied. In the example, even on mac OS X 10.8 or iOS 6 and ARC enabled, one need to explicitly copy the block `block` in order to shift it onto the heap. Otherwise, `block` remains on the stack, and the asynchronously invoked block `async_block` will crash.

Comment: I've to revise my last statement that the block `block` will not automatically copied. Please see my answer.

Comment: As CouchDeveloper found out, blocks inside a block will be copied. While it's true that blocks are objects, they sometimes receive a special treatment like in this case.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Well I have no idea how Apple implemented their `_NSBlock`s but GNUstep's `GSBlock` contained a private subclass for blocks on stack called `_NSBlock` (Clever implementation!). When it is sent `[block retain]` (or `objc_retain(block)` if you use ARC) it is copied instead of simply retained and got its class changed. That is just an override of a method, coupled with some Objective-C runtime magic. Try copy some `CFArray`s with Objective-C code and you can see a similar behaviour.