# Loading resource_bundle error in cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, nsbundle

I am trying to make my own cocoapods, I used images. 
When I follow the tutorial, I get an error.

**.podspec**

```
  s.resource_bundles = {
    'SSSlidingSelector' => ['SSSlidingSelector/Assets/*.xcassets']
  }
```

**Class/SlidingSelector.m**

```c
- (UIImage *)getImageWithName:(NSString *)imageName {
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
    NSURL *url = [bundle URLForResource:@"SSSlidingSelector" withExtension:@"bundle"];
    NSBundle *targetBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:url];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName
                                inBundle:targetBundle
           compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil];
    return image;
}
```

**error**

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSBundle initWithURL:]: nil URL argument'
```

**Screenshot**
[image: Resource path]
[image]

What is wrong with my code?
thks

Comment: I just tested this and the function is working as expected. Which version of Cocoapods are you using?

Comment: 1.7.5 @alxlives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your code.

Cocoapods on version 1.0.1 supports Assets Catalogs. Please check if yours isn't below it running `pod --version` in Terminal.

If a new `pod install` does not solved, there is an issue with the xCode New Build System on Assets Catalogs (as mentioned [Here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8122)) that could be your problem.

You can change the Build System on `File` > `Workspace Settings...` > `Build System`. Try setting it to `Legacy Build System`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIImage *)getImageWithName:(NSString *)imageName {
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName
                                inBundle:bundle
           compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil];
    return image;
}
```