# How to make dispatch_async nil out block

Tags: ios, block, dispatch-async

I was reading this:
[does dispatch_async copy internal blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157360/does-dispatch-async-copy-internal-blocks)

and I want to know how to get dispatch-async to nil out the block it copied onto the heap so that the block can be garbage collected.

Ok, so on the local stack, I create my block:

```
MyBlock aBlock = ^{
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            NSLog(@"holder is: %p, holder.block is %p", holder, holder.block);
            sleep(1);
        }
    };

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create(NULL, DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
dispatch_async(queue, aBlock);

sleep(2);     // give the queue some time to start executing the block
```

The block keeps executing simply because it is the block on the heap that is copied by dispatch_async. This is all expected behavior.

So my question is....is there a way to explicitly make this block on the heap be destroyed ?

Or will ARC memory manage that block for me from the heap when the dispatch_async has finished executing, and I personally can't do anything about it ?

Thank you!

Comment: The block is still running. You can't destroy it while it's running, but it will be destroyed when it's done.

Comment: so when the block on the queue is finished running, ARC will destroy it right? Is there anyway I can programmatically destroy it?

Comment: Do you mean you want to terminate the loop early ?

Comment: why does this "holder" need a reference to the block? why not just get rid of this `block` property and just do `dispatch_async(queue, aBlock);`?

Comment: @Wain yes! I would like to terminate the loop early. How would I do that?

Comment: @newacct ah true, that would of made the question much more simple. I will rephrase

Comment: (1) ARC is not garbage collection. (2) If you want a block-based operation framework with simple cancellation ability, consider `NSOperationQueue` instead.

Comment: @AaronBrager thanks, let me correctly re phrase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your updated question, you don't need to `nil` anything. The block on the heap is just like any other reference counted object. Your scope has a strong reference to it for the duration of the scope of the variable `aBlock`. And the asynchronous dispatch mechanism holds a strong reference to it until it has executed. When there are no strong references to it anymore, it is deallocated.

Comment: your statement:
"Your scope has a strong reference to it for the duration of the scope of the variable aBlock."

can you clarify? Do you mean:

1) block goes on stack
2) some Object (or dispatch_async) copy references that block. Thus, that block goes onto the heap.

3) the stack now has a strong reference to the block on the heap. 

So at 3), does the stack pop the original block, and create a strong reference to the block in the heap?

Comment: @rtsao: First, don't worry about the stack/heap thing and think about it as always heap like other objects. Then it makes sense right? The stack/heap thing is an implementation detail and as long as you copy a block instead of retain, it will work correctly. (Copying a block moves it to the heap.) ARC should take care of copying for you.

Comment: @rtsao: What ARC does here is not known to us, but for example it could 1) copy the block (moving it to the heap) immediately after definition when assigning to `aBlock`; then `aBlock` would be a strong reference, and it would release it at the end of the scope of `aBlock`; the dispatch_async will still copy it when you pass it and release it when it is done executing the block. Alternately, it could 2) not copy the block and not release it in this scope; it will initially be on the stack; the dispatch_async will still copy the block and move it to the heap, and release it when it's done.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a BOOL property to the class BlockHolder for example :

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter = isCancelled) BOOL cancelled;
```

and inside the block add a test to check if the block is cancelled or not like this :

```
__block BlockHolder * holder = [[BlockHolder alloc] init];
MyBlock aBlock = ^{
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if(holder.isCancelled) return;
            NSLog(@"holder is: %p, holder.block is %p", holder, holder.block);
            sleep(1);
        }
    };
```

and if you want to cancel the block you can set the value of cancelled to YES.
I hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to cancel the loop you need to put a check inside and break out when the condition isn't met. That could be that your container object is now nil, or it could be the result of some method call. Just be sure that you aren't retaining or influencing the test you add by testing for it...